# Making prev() on first index of array return the last index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I'm looking for a way to make the `prev()` function to keep rewinding (starting from the end instead) when used on the first index. Consider the following example:

```
$foo = array(1, 2, , ..., 12);
echo current($foo) // output: 1
echo prev($foo) // should output 12 - returns FALSE
```

I could, of course, write a function to somehow satisfy my needs, but I'm pretty sure that I must be overlooking something since this is pretty simple behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myPrev(&$array) {
    if(prev($array) === false) {
        return end($array);
    }
    return prev($array);
}
```

Do you think something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [end()](http://php.net/end), its designed like this for a reason.